# How to change the customize Window title bar and its icon for multiple activities

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity

I am able to  customize the Window title bar and its icon by following the below Link :-

http://androidcodesnippetsblog.blogspot.in/2013/03/custom-window-title-bar-in-android.html

But I want to have different title for different activities running in the same project.Is there any way to fix from one particular xml to have title bar and icon for multiple activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just Set imageview and textview id in your custom layout and set dynamically its value in particular Activity

```
ImageView image=(Imageview)getWindow().findViewById(your image view id);
TextView title=(Textview)getWindow().findViewById(your image view id);
```

set `image.setImageResource(...);`
and `title.settext(title);`

Thats it....

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having the theme on your application tag change it to your activity instead. For example:

```
      <activity
        android:theme="@style/themeForAcitivy"
        android:name="MyActivity">
      </activity>
```

You can also call `getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.myCustomBar)` on each activity to create a custom ActionBar view if that works for you too.